# Using JSObject in applet to communicate with browser

Tags: java, javascript, applet

In my applet, I want to comunicate with browser through

```
win = (JSObject) JSObject.getWindow(this);
```

This line is called in *init()* method of applet.

First time everything work's fine,  at the end of process page is reloaded and applet destroyed. But second time *win* object seems to be unavailable, in fact if i try to access it i obtain

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at sun.plugin2.message.Queue.waitForMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe$2.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.util.Waiter$1.wait(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.util.Waiter.runAndWait(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe.receive(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.waitForReply(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.eval(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Using param **separate_jvm** in applet seems to solve the problem (see documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html#SEPARATE%5FJVM))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Applet: Call JavaScript - JSObject.getWindow(this) returns always null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403131/java-applet-call-javascript-jsobject-getwindowthis-returns-always-null)